Field redefinitions in the Higgs mechanism
Consider the Higg's mechanism for a simple $U(1)$ theory. Leaving aside the lagrangian which consists of a kinetic term for the gauge field, a covariant derivative term and the potential term for the complex scalar field. Suppose, we have found the vacuum and now expand the field about this vacuum.
There are two ways of parametrizing the fluctuations about the vacuum, as follows
$$(v + \eta(x) +i\omega(x))$$
$$(v+h(x))e^{i\Omega(x)/v}.$$
These are supposed to be equivalent, and to first order expansion in $\Omega(x) $is  the same expression. In both cases, the fields $\eta(x)$ and $h(x)$ get a mass, while $\omega(x)$ and $\Omega(x)$ don't. The latter are interpreted as the goldstone bosons, which can be gauged away by choosing the unitary gauge.
My confusion is regarding the Higg's field. In most references, $h(x)$ is interpreted as the Higg's field. However, $\eta(x)$ could have been equivalently considered to be the Higg's field. Initially I thought that since fields are not observables, and a higg's particle could equivalently be $h(x)$ or $\eta(x)$ as these are just field redefinitions, and the $S$-matrix is invariant to such field redefinitions.
However, field redefinitions are of the form $A(x) \rightarrow f(A(x))$.
Hence, if I had something like $\eta(x) = f(h(x))$, then I would be convinced.
However in our case,  $\eta(x) = f(h(x),\Omega(x))$ and $\omega(x) = g(h(x),\Omega(x))$.
In that case, the $S$-matrix for $\eta(x)$ would be different from $h(x)$. In that case, the fields are not just simple redefinitions of each other. Is this argument valid. If it is, then is choosing $h(x)$ to be the Higgs particle just a convention?

As an additional note to the comment below: There is often a preferred choice of field redefinition if chase we are looking at weakly coupled perturbative QFT. Here the choice is to pick the redefinitions such that the free part of the action is diagonal and has no linear terms.  (And is canonically normalized). This allows for the whole Feynman diagram picture to simplify e.g. there are no propagators with ''different'' particles at vanishing coupling. This may yield what is commonly referred to as the preferred Higgs definition (though I would have to check that explicitly)

It is ok to have field redefinitions that involve multiple fields. Ie, something like $A^i(x)\rightarrow f^j (A^i(x))$ (where $i,j=1, \cdots, N$ and $N$ is the number of fields) can be a valid field redefinition.
The main properties a field redefinition should have to behave "nicely" is that it is (a) invertible and (b) local.  The relationships between $h,\Omega$ and $\eta, \omega$ are invertible and local, so you are ok here.
Therefore the S-matrices of the two theories will be the same.
